# Why did I get the Pundit badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, comment-badges

It might be a bit weird, but I am wondering why I got the [Pundit badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/94/pundit) some time ago. It is supposed to be given to people that have 10 comments of score 5 or more. However, I found several queries that will check my comment score and all of them give me number of 7 for such comments:

- http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/1108032/comments?sort=votes&min=5 (I have put in my user id)
- https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/947/my-comment-score-distribution

Do you think this is a bug, or are there some comments I should also count? I have only meta and Stack Overflow accounts and I have no such comments in the meta site.

Comment: You might find the comments have since been deleted. Your badge will not be rescinded in this instance, making it seem you "shouldn't have earnt it"

Comment: @Matt Not the case - I ran that query very often, never even approached the count. However it is possible that comments on deleted questions are counted and the queries do not count them

Comment: It's likely that the comments were deleted with a post, or purged altogether on a post that wasn't deleted. In any event, you did earn the badge. Scores are kept in either scenario, and (I believe) count toward the badge.

Answer (score 9):

It seems the pundit badge also counts previously deleted comments with a score of 5 or higher.

Yesterday I was awarded the pundit badge on [Sustainability SE](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com) but according to [this API2 query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-on-users#order=desc&sort=votes&ids=99&filter=!-pOXn(uw&site=sustainability&run=true) I only have 7 comments that qualify. However I know of at least 2 questions that were deleted months ago where I made a comment with score 5. So the only logical explanation is that comments on deleted posts also count towards the badge, no matter when they were deleted.

BTW the StackExchange Data Explorer (SEDE) is only updated every once in a while so your second query may not show your latest comments or comment upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

I just queried the database: 3 of your 10 comments were on posts that are now deleted. Of course, at the time you were awarded the Pundit badge, those posts weren't deleted yet.

Comment: I am very sorry to argue with moderator, but I doubt it they were deleted after I was awarded the badge. As I already mentioned I monitored my progress on the badge very intensely, it is very unlikely I missed 3 comments. Can you please verify once more when the posts were deleted? Mind if you share the info about them?

Comment: Your comments on deleted posts were "Really a ton of code and a phrase like 'It will take me a while to fix the errors, please fix them for me'? People are optimistic", "Badly indented, the question seems like `How to calculate a + b if I have b and a`. Too much unnecessary code, especially the layout, duplicated code.", and "Too much code, try to localize only the part of it that is relevant to the question. Did not work is not enough - explain the result. Also I do not see you using `toString` anywhere in the program.".

Comment: @Emmett I strongly suspect that the last sentence of your post is incorrect.