# Pundit badge: Do moved comments count?

Tags: support, comments, chat, badges

I wrote a comment on a question and was getting up votes, 13 last time I was able to check. I later logged in to see how many votes it had (This was the first time one of my comments had gotten a bunch of upvotes, so I was excitingly tracking it), and was disappointed that my +13 comment had been moved to chat because others had been discussing the question. My question is: Will that ex-comment count towards the pundit badge? Also, out of curiosity, do mods have to move all the comments when they move comments?

Comment: It depends a bit I think how the script is triggered. If it runs as soon as an comment reaches the threshold and you are eligible for the badges, it gets awarded. Awarded, non-tag, badges don't get revoked if you drop under the threshold. If you didn't reach threshold, you would have to wait for your next comment to reach 5 upvotes but in that case comments that are moved to chat will no longer count. Needs a dev to confirm how this actually works. The move to chat is similar to what users get offered after 5 comments and all comments are moved. In special cases a mod can undelete a comment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the comment has to be live at the time the script runs, which for Pundit might only be daily.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183059 seems to indicate that the answer is no.

Comment: On the other hand, still-present comments on deleted posts appear to be counted: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163502/why-did-i-get-the-pundit-badge